# Cannot return HTML file from SpringBoot either as string or ModelAndView

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot Application, and want to return a html page (with a token using thymeleaf) on an API call. The problem is SpringBoot gives a 404 saying it cannot find the endpoint (It can if I don't try to return a html page).

What I want is to be able to return the HTML page somehow with thymeleaf replacing the ${token} value.

Project Structure (Only controller and resources are important)

[image]

MainApplication

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableJpaRepositories({ "com.ps.oms.client.repository", "com.ps.oms.user.repository",
        "com.ps.oms.admin.BrokerDisable.repository" })
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(UserApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@Slf4j
public class AccountController {
    
    @GetMapping("/reset-password")
    public String showResetPasswordForm(@Param(value = "token") String token, Model model) {
        
        model.addAttribute("token", token);
        return "reset_password_form"; //this never works
        //return "redirect:/reset_password_form.html"; //this works if html file in static folder but cannot use thymeleaf
    }
}
```

HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- removed css -->

<title>Reset Password</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="logoblock">
        <p class="logoname">Order Management System</p>
    </div>
    <form class="reset-form">

        <label class="headlabel">Reset Your Password</label>
        <p th:text="${token}">Hi!</p>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="newPsw" class="psw-field" type="password" name="newPassword"
                placeholder="Enter New Password"> <span class="input-icon"><i
                class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="confPsw" class="psw-field" type="password" name="confirmPassword"
                placeholder="Confirm Password"> <span class="input-icon"><i
                class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" onclick="savePass(event)" class="reset-btn">Reset</button>
    </form>
    

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script th:inline="javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        savePass(event);
    });
});

function savePass(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var pswData = {
            newPassword: $("#newPsw").val(),
            confirmPassword:$("#confPsw").val(),
        }
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/v1/reset-password',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data){alert(data.message);},
        error: function(data){alert(data.responseJSON.message);},
        data: JSON.stringify(pswData)
    });
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CORS configuration (I don't know if this does anything)

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/v1/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS");
                }
        };
    }
}
```

Security Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

I have the following dependencies in POM.xml which might be related to it

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

add your html filename in web.xml file.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
    <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/index.hml</url-pattern>
```